# Fancybox is not working well with a form inside

Tags: jquery, fancybox

**PROBLEM:**

I have a fancybox that is triggered when user doesn't have geolocation activated. This fancybox has a form inside, just an input with 2 buttons and   what I want to do is to let user introduce a text and when he hits some button, just do some task. All looks good, but when I hit the button I just can see an error in the console and nothings happens.

As I said, all looks good, I can see in developer tools that events are correctly joined. Other fancyboxes don't give me any problem.

**CODE:**

```
HTML:

<div id="modal-info0" style="display:none" data-fancybox="">
    <div class="container noborder">
        <div class="row hcenter">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-push-2">
                <div class="alert pad-sm">
                    <i class="icon-alert icon-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <p class="title title-sm">Text</p>
                </div>
                <ul class="grid cols4 insights d-flex flex-justify-content-center" style="display: none ! important;">
                    <li>
                        <i class="icon-alert icon-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <p>Text</p>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <p class="t-xl vmar-xl">Text</p>
                <form class="form-border" id="formBuscadorClinicasDentalesCP">
                    <div class="row vmar-md">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <label class="hright" for="cp">CP</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-8 col-lg-6">
                            <i class="icon-location" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            <input name="cp" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" type="text">
                            <div class="pagination vmar">
                                <ul class="btns w12">
                                    <li>
                                        <button class="btn" type="submit" name="enviar">
                                            <span>Accept</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="">
                                        <button type="submit" name="enviar" class="btn sec pull-right">
                                            <span>Cancel</span>
                                        </button>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

JS:

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fancybox.open({
        src  : '#modal-info0',
        type : 'inline',
        opts : {
            afterShow : function( instance, current ) {
            console.info( 'done!' );
            }
        }
    });
});

$('#formBuscadorClinicasDentalesCP').on('submit', function (e) {
    alert("IN!");
    return false;
});
</script>
```

**ERROR:**

> TypeError: r.current.opts.$orig is undefined

**ERROR IMAGE:**

[image: Error image]

**FURTHER INFORMATION**

If I bind click event to button instead of form, it is triggered without any problem. This error just occurs if I bind submit event to form.

Comment: Maybe try changing `type : 'inline'` to `type : 'html'`

Comment: Doesn't work...

Comment: Well, since you did not proved a link to a live demo, it is quite impossible to help.

Comment: Why don't you use codepen to create a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got solution. Just remove data-fancybox="" from the div you want to convert to fancybox and it will work perfectly.